# i want to do something depending on how many time the index[1] occurs on the list

Tags: python

i have this csv list:

```
aaa;aaa;aaa1
aaa;aaa;aaa2 
bbb;bbb;bbb1 
ccc;ccc;ccc1
```

i want to do something depending on how many time the index[1] occurs on the list.
so in the list, i have two lines with the same index[1]. so when this happens i want to do something, else i want to do something that will be the case of the last two lines in the list.

Something like this? :

```
for line in read :
    if line[1] != last:
        count = 1
        last = line[1]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Here wat is ``index[1]`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last = None
count = 0
for line in read:
    if last is not None and line[1] == last:
        count += 1
        # Take some action if necessary
        continue

    count = 1
    last = line[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find repeated occurences in a list with **`count`**:

```
if read.count(line) > 1
```